# pandas dataframe to oracle - NotImplementedError

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, oracle11g, anaconda, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert a pandas dataframe in to oracle table with the following code:

```
 tabl.to_sql('RESULT', cnxn, flavor='oracle', if_exists='replace');
```

however, I am running in to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pp.py", line 125, in <module>
    tabl.to_sql('RESULT', cnxn, flavor='oracle', if_exists='replace');
  File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 950, in to_sql
    index_label=index_label)
  File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 467, in to_sql
    pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con, flavor=flavor)
  File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 521, in pandasSQL_builder
    return PandasSQLLegacy(con, flavor, is_cursor=is_cursor)
  File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1017, in __init__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

I've cx_oracle installed. Pandas version is 0.14.1 ( from Anaconda-2.1). Any lights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle is supported through SQLAlchemy (in fact, all database flavors that can be used with SQLAlchemy are supported). Therefore you need to make a [SQLAlchemy engine](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.cx_oracle):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@tnsname')

tabl.to_sql('RESULT', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

See the explanation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries. You need at least pandas >= 0.14 for this.
Previously, through the `flavor` keyword, indeed only sqlite and mysql were supported, as @cel points out. This `flavor` is now deprecated, and only `sqlite` will remain supported without using sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), you find that currently the `flavor` argument can only be `sqlite` or `mysql`.

```
flavor : {‘sqlite’, ‘mysql’}, default ‘sqlite’
    The flavor of SQL to use. Ignored when using SQLAlchemy engine.
    ‘mysql’ is deprecated and will be removed in future versions, but it will be
    further supported through SQLAlchemy engines.
```

The raised `NotImplementedError` here is rather obscure. There is already a merged [patch](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/8fe1cf6d1931071c378fcc3170b82a145a037da0) at `github` that improves the error message.

Comment: Isn't there any other means to insert other than this? :(. Or should I go with looping "INSERT"? 

Any help would be much appreciated.